# Agda: How to check the type even when file doesn't typecheck yet?

Tags: agda, agda-mode

In agda-mode there is `C-c C-d` command to infer a type of expression. This is especially needed when we arrive at a type error! But exactly then this command doesn't work. I would guess that this is because the feature wants to evaluate the expression type in the context of the working file. Rightfully so - but is there a way to bypass it and for example find the expression type in the context of the longest typechecking prefix of a file?

I'm using *agda-mode* for *vs-code* but *emacs* tips are appreciated as well as they hopefully translate.

Also did I miss some feature to infer the type of expression at cursor? The way I use `C-c C-d` (infer type) is after this command I input the expression of interest manually (or paste it). Would be nice to get a type of the word the cursor points to.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth knowing a bit more about your situation. For example, is there something stopping you commenting out the end of the file, or commenting out the ill typed expression and replacing it by a hole?

Comment: No, this is a valid solution just an inconvenient one.

Comment: The fact that holes exist should result in files that always typecheck, I don't see why your situation would happen in a relevant development. Agda files are built step by step, and should typecheck throughout the whole process, until no more holes are left unfilled.